# How to implement IPlatformParameters in PageRenderer for Android in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to implement a PageRenderer for the page:

I have a MainPage.xaml and its code behind contain : IPlatformParamters

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
 public IPlatformParameters platformParameters { get; set; }

 ...... other code....

}
```

Implementing a Custom PageRenderer.

below class with name: MyPageRenderer is in Project.IOS

How to convert this iOS for Android?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]

   namespace ProjectX.iOS
    {
        class MyPageRenderer: PageRenderer
        {
            MainPage page;

             protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
             {
                 base.OnElementChanged (e);
                 page = e.NewElement as MainPage;
             }

            public override void ViewDidLoad ()
             {
                 base.ViewDidLoad ();
                 page.platformParameters = new PlatformParameters(this);
             }

       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code how to render the page in Xamarin form Android.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
    namespace ProjectX.Droid
    {
        public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
        {
            MainPage page;
            public CameraPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                if (e. NewElement != null)
                {
                     page = e.NewElement as MainPage;
                }


              page.platformParameters = new PlatformParameters(Forms.Context);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error :What is control? and what namespace for this control ?  The 'this' can not convert to android.App.Activty.

Comment: try to pass Forms.Context place of this check my updated code]